# Android Create PromptDialog class

Tags: android

The class:

```
public class PromptDialog extends DialogFragment{
    public interface IPromptDialogListener{
        public void onPromptDialogOk(String promptText);
    }

    private Context _context;
    private IPromptDialogListener _consumer;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        final EditText prompt=new EditText(_context);
        builder.setView(prompt);
        builder.setTitle("The Title");
        builder.setMessage("The Message");

        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                _consumer.onPromptDialogOk(prompt.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                // Canceled.
            }
        });

        builder.show();
        return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void showPrompt(IPromptDialogListener consumer,Context context,FragmentManager fragmentManager){
        _consumer=consumer;
        _context=context;
        show(fragmentManager,"prompt");
    }
}
```

The activity:
    public class TheActivity extends Activity
        implements PromptDialog.IPromptDialogListener{

```
    PromptDialog promptDialog;

    public void btNuevaRuta_click(View view){
        if (promptDialog==null){
            promptDialog=new PromptDialog();
        }
        promptDialog.showPrompt(this,this,getFragmentManager());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPromptDialogOk(String promptText) {
        Toast.makeText(this,promptText,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

The result:
When open the prompt dialog, show this:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/TVzZMCe.png]

After press back button:
[image]

And finally the text is shown:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vKiU.png

What happens when the dialog open?

Comment: Nobody knows who's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error.
The last lines of Class PromptDialog opened two dialogues...

You just have to return the dialogue created and self-generated deleting

The lines:

```
    builder.show();
    return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
```

Replaced by:

```
    return builder.show();
    //return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
```